# Using spectral library

Tags: remote-sensing, open-source-gis

I want to classify an Aster image using the [ASTER Spectral Library - Version 2.0](http://speclib.jpl.nasa.gov/)

Anyone here ever done this?

Any suggestions?

I'm using open source GIS and Remote Sensing software.

Answer (score 2):

You can use it for linear spectral unmixing. You can find some literature about this here:

http://scholar.google.it/scholar?q=spectral+unmixing

NB: I have written a linear spectral unmixing (i.spec.unmix) for GRASS GIS in 1999, it is available in GRASS Addons but needs some updates for GRASS 6.